# Pivot Cloud Foundry error: "Browser detection failed and system property h2.browser not set" - Spring Boot 2

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I'm trying to `cf push` my spring boot app to Pivot Cloud Foundry, but the container fails to start. This is the error output:

```
   2018-08-21T12:48:55.34+0200 [CELL/0] OUT Starting health monitoring of container
   2018-08-21T12:48:55.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT JVM Memory Configuration: -Xmx427509K -Xss1M -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=240M -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=10M -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=109066K
   2018-08-21T12:48:55.81+0200 [APP/PROC/WEB/0] OUT Failed to start a browser to open the URL http://10.246.203.10:8082: Browser detection failed and system property h2.browser not set
   2018-08-21T12:49:56.15+0200 [HEALTH/0] ERR Failed to make TCP connection to port 8080: connection refused
   2018-08-21T12:49:56.15+0200 [CELL/0] ERR Timed out after 1m0s: health check never passed.
```

I tried to set the h2.browser property to "opera", `false` and `true` in Application.yml but that did not solve the problem. I also removed the h2 dependency because I don't want to use h2 in PCF and rebuilded the artifact before `cf push`. When I run the JAR file, it opens my browser with the h2 webinterface (I don't want that).

What am I missing here?

EDIT: I think I might need to pass an argument to the java app in PCF to disable the console (browser part) of H2 but not sure..

**Application.yml:**

```
  datasource:
    driverClassName: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    url: jdbc:mysql://my_url_here
    username: my_username_here
    password: my_password_here
  jpa:
    hibernate.ddl-auto: none
    show_sql: false
```

**manifest.yml**

```
---
applications:
- name: cookie-backend
  memory: 1024M
  instances: 1
  random-route: true
  buildpack: java_buildpack
  path: out/artifacts/cookie_backend_jar/cookie-backend.jar
  services:
  - mysql
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com</groupId>
    <artifactId>cookie</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>cookie</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.javafaker</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafaker</artifactId>
            <version>0.15</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Solved it for now by creating a complete new Spring project and adding all classes one-by-one.

Comment: If you run `mvn dependency:tree` you can see what is pulling in the H2 dependency. If you don't need it, exclude the dependency. There's not a lot of detail, but it seems like Spring Boot is trying to auto configure something for H2 that should only be configured in a local/dev environment. If you exclude H2, Spring Boot won't try to auto configure it. Another thing you could do, if you hit this again is add the `--debug` flag, which will cause Spring Boot to dump a lot of information about what it's doing on your behalf.

Comment: Thanks for the response @DanielMikusa!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by first starting a new Spring project, secondly importing all the dependancies in my new project POM file and and than adding back all classes (code) in that order. I ended up with a new project on the same codebase without the error.

This is not the exact answer to what was going wrong with it, but it might be helpfull for someone trying to solve the same problem. I'm using h2 now on a production server. Also, the answer from @Daniel in respond to the issue might be helpful.